# can sql be excuted in sequence in preparedstatement in ORacle RAC

Tags: oracle, prepared-statement

We add insert sql by using prepared statmenet

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_TABLE_LOCK_SQL);
        for(String key : newKeys){
            ps.setString(1, key);
            ps.addBatch();
}

ps.executeBatch()
```

Any one can tell me the preparedstament will be executed in sequence in ORacle RAC all the time?

Comment: Can you re phrase your question? I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: if you want to insert some data in order then you have to use sequence in data or time stamp , then only we can  select the data in that order .